# Prevent evaluation of exponentials in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, evaluation, exponential

I'm using SymPy as a code generator for functions that contain many exponentials. Hence, it is important for numerical stability that the arguments of the exponentials are not evaluated. I want to prevent this:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
>>> expr = sp.exp(5.*x - 10.)
>>> print(expr)
4.53999297624849e-5*exp(5.0*x)
```

As it can lead to numerically inaccurate results.

I can prevent the evaluation of the exponentials as follows:

```
>>> expr = sp.exp(5.*x - 10., evaluate=False)
>>> print(expr)
exp(5.0*x - 10.0)
```

However, when I perform operations like a substitution or differentiation on the expression, the exponential is evaluated again:

```
>>> expr = sp.exp(5.*x - 10., evaluate=False)
>>> expr.subs(x, y)
4.53999297624849e-5*exp(5.0*y)
>>> expr.diff(x, 1)
5.0*(4.53999297624849e-5*exp(5.0*x))
```

What is the correct way in SymPy to prevent the evaluation of the exponential under such operations?

Comment: This is a long shot, but if numerical stability of such an expression matters to you, could it be that you want to use `expm1` under the hood?

Comment: Not sure how this would help with my use case. The problem was that the argument of the exponential was evaluated and that the non-symbolic parts are written as a prefactor in the code generation. These prefactors could either be extremely small or extremely large, leading to inaccurate results in the multiplication.

Comment: As I said, it was a long shot. If you are working with numbers that are so small or large that you get inaccuracies due to this, you may want to switch to the logarithmic domain. However, given how floating-point numbers are implemented, I still find this unlikely. There is only a small range (of orders of magnitude) where you run into inaccuracies, but not into overflow errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious point is that you are using float for integer values e.g.:

```
In [8]: exp(5*x - 10)                                                                                                             
Out[8]: 
 5⋅x - 10
ℯ        

In [9]: exp(5.*x - 10.)                                                                                                           
Out[9]: 
                     5.0⋅x
4.53999297624849e-5⋅ℯ
```

Maybe in your real problem you want to work with non-integers. Again rationals should be used for exact calculations:

```
In [10]: exp(Rational(1, 3)*x - S(3)/2)                                                                                           
Out[10]: 
 x   3
 ─ - ─
 3   2
ℯ
```

Perhaps your input numbers are not really rational and you have them as Python floats but you want to keep them from evaluating. You can use symbols and then only substitute for them when evaluating:

```
In [13]: exp(a*x + b).evalf(subs={a:5.0, b:10.})                                                                                  
Out[13]: 
 a⋅x + b
ℯ       

In [14]: exp(a*x + b).evalf(subs={x:1, a:5.0, b:10.})                                                                             
Out[14]: 3269017.37247211

In [15]: exp(a*x + b).subs({a:5.0, b:10.})                                                                                        
Out[15]: 
                  5.0⋅x
22026.4657948067⋅ℯ
```

If all of these seems awkward and you really do just want to stuff floats in and prevent evaluation then you can use `UnevaluatedExpr`:

```
In [21]: e = exp(UnevaluatedExpr(5.0)*x - UnevaluatedExpr(10.))                                                                   

In [22]: e                                                                                                                        
Out[22]: 
 x⋅5.0 - 10.0
ℯ            

In [23]: e.doit()    # doit triggers evaluation                                                                                                             
Out[23]: 
                     5.0⋅x
4.53999297624849e-5⋅ℯ
```

Comment: The last suggestion seems to do it for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If this is sufficient you should mark the answer as accepted.

Since you mention "numerical stability" I should say that using evalf with the subs argument is the best of the options above for numerical accuracy.